# Translating the following C++ code into Nim

Tags: c++, sorting, for-loop, nim-lang

I'm trying to learn Nim by converting different pieces of code, and I've stumbled upon something which I've never seen before.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
...
for(int t=q&1?u+x:u+x>>1;t>1;)t/=p[++cnt]=sieve[t];
...
sort(p+1,p+cnt+1);
```

I understand what the ternary operator is and how it works, what I don't quite get is what's going on with the variables "t" and "cnt" (both integers) and the array "p" (an array of integers). How does using an increment as the index of "p" work?

Then there's the sort function, in which I completely gave up because I couldn't find any documentation on what it does (the fact that it's taking an integer added to an array obviously doesn't help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first start of by making the code a little more readable.  A little bit of whitespace never hurt anybody.

```
for(int t = (q & 1? u + x: u + x >> 1); t > 1;)
{
    t /= p[++cnt] = sieve[t];
}
```

> what's going on with the variables "t" and "cnt" (both integers) and the array "p" (an array of integers)

So `t` is being set to either `u + x` or `u + x >> 1` depending on what `q & 1` is.  Then inside the loop we are dividing t by whatever the value of `sieve` at the index of `t` is.  We are also assign that value to the `p` array at the position of `++cnt`.  `++cnt` is using the [pre increment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) to increase the value of `cnt` by 1 and then using that value for the index of `p`.

> Then there's the sort function, in which I completely gave up because I couldn't find any documentation on what it does

For this I am assuming they are using the [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function.  When dealing with arrays the name of the array is treated as a pointer to the first element of the array.  So when we see `sort(p+1,p+cnt+1);` you can translate it to `sort(one from the begining of the array, cnt + 1 elements from the begining of the array);`.  So this is going to sort all of the elements in the array from one from the begining of the array to one less than cnt + 1 elements from the begining of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to learn Nim as you said, or trying to learn C?  Both things you asked about are pretty basic c:

++cnt has the side effect (cnt=cnt+1) combined with the value that cnt ends up with.  That value is used as the index.  The side effect is a side effect.

p+1 and p+cnt are each pointers.  The name of an array is treated as a constant pointer to the first element of that array in most uses within C.  A pointer plus an integer is another pointer, pointing that number of elements past the original.